# Confusion about modifying column in dataframe with pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm working on a Bangaluru House Price Data csv from Kaggle. There is a column called 'total_sqft'. In this column, there are values that are a range of numbers (e.g.: 1000-1500), and I want to identify all those entries. I created this function to do so:

```
def is_float(x):
  try:
    float(x)
  except:
    return False
  return True
```

I applied it to the column:

```
df3[~df3['total_sqft'].apply(is_float)]
```

This works, but I don't understand why this doesn't:

```
df3['total_sqft'] = ~df3['total_sqft'].apply(is_float)
```

This just returns 'False' for everything instead of the actual entries

Comment: In the first version you are selecting the rows that contain true values from the apply function. In the second you are setting the values to be the values of the apply function. Tilde means negation btw.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer from comment:**

> In the first version you are selecting the rows that contain true values from the apply function. In the second you are setting the values to be the values of the apply function. Tilde means negation btw.